# JQuery Two colour slider control automatic move

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, slider

I am creating a slider control with two colours for media player streaming. [Covered portion with one color remaining with another]

Working: i can drag/ move the slider manually.

Needs: I want to move the slider automatically.(1. Once the control is ready and 2. After changing the position of the slider, from that position it has to move automatically)

Code:

```
        var slider1 = new Control.Slider('handle1', 'track1', {
            animate: true,
            range: $R(0, 10),
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
            sliderValue: 5,
            startSpan: 'span1',
            onChange: function(v) { handleSliderChange(v); }
        });
```

Plugins:

```
    <script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Edit:

```
Is there any other slider control with these qualities?
```

Geetha.